# Add table privileges to user using mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've created a user using the server administration tools in mySQL workbench and can assign global and database permissions to those users from the administration tool.

Is there a way to assign those users (stored in mysql.users) table level privileges in mySQL Workbench?

Thanks

Comment: The good 'n old "grant xxx on yyy.table to peter"

Comment: See the MySQL `GRANT` syntax reference. Table-level privileges are possible. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did find a workaround.  Not elegant, but it works.

1. Open your database as an EER Model.
2. 2 tabs will open, go to the one that is not selected by default (MySQL Model).
3. Follow the [directions here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-model-overview-privileges.html) to add roles/users.
4. Forward Engineer the model back to the database. You can deselect all objects except the users.
5. You can either have Workbench create the users, or, if you already have the users, just set the grant statements

Not pretty, but it works

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly there's no way you can do that in Workbench Administrator module, as of WB 5.2.37.

You can always grant the access using SQL commands (see previous comments) in Workbench's SQL Query Editor. Just don't forget to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after that.